# Windows Server 2008 R2 setting an overall disk quota (not per user)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, disk-space

I'm setting up a disk partition specifically for MySQL Community Edition database logs.  I would like to be notified when disk space has reached a threshold (say 85% full).  It looks like disk quotas can be set up per user, but I don't care about individual users, just the overall disk space.  Is this possible, or are there any other alternatives?  At my work environment it's difficult to get permission to install random software, so I would like to focus on OS controls if possible.

Comment: Disk quotas don't strike me as the right tool for the job. You may not be able to install `random` software but how about installing `specific` software that can monitor and alert on disk space?

Comment: Can you please tell us what DB software you're using?  I'm more than willing to bet that your DB will have a good way to monitor the amount of space it's utilizing and warn you as it gets close to the threshold.

Comment: We're using MySQL (Community Version) which is pretty bare bones.  I don't believe there is any built in monitoring (As far as I can tell, we need to get the paid version for that)

Comment: Are you using MySQL Workbench or some other application to access the DB?

Comment: @jkovba We're using this for some internal webapps.  I don't know if the system admins use Workbench, but I've been getting by with the CLI.  The webapps connect through their various ORMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My google-fu was lacking earlier.  I found that there is a built in tool called "File Server Resource Manager" (FSRM) in Windows Server 2008 R2.  It can be used to notify via email when a volume reaches a certain threshold.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  See here for more info: [technet info for FSRM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758763%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Another way to do this would be to use the Performance Monitor to send an email alert when disk space reaches a set threshold as described [at this blog](http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2012/10/monitoring-free-drive-space-with.html).  This would also suit my needs, but since it looks like FSRM best meets my needs, I'll going to try and use that.